# Error in DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2005, dataset

I am making `Windows Application`,In that I am creating dataset for making report,for that i am using a query which  already ran sucessfully for showing data in grid.But its not working for dataset.

**Query**:

```
select sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as BuyQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyAmount,

       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as SellQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellAmount
from tradeFile
where Party_Code=@pcode and Sauda_Date like @saudaDate% and Scrip_Code=@scripCode
```

Its giving me error for % near Sauda_Date like @saudaDate%.If i removes % it does not give error,But it doesnt give me intended result.

**query text**:

```
Error in WHERE clause near 'AND'.
Unable to parse query text.
```

Is there another method for writing like-% queries for dataset?

Please help me.

Comment: you are facing problem of string concatenation...

Comment: What is the type of `Sauda_Date`?

Comment: @trailmax : post it as answer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman no i got the solution. +'%' was problem.

Comment: You have to wrap the value with percents instead, e.g.: `...SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saudaDate", String.Format("%{0}%", saudaDate));`.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
string query="select sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as BuyQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=1 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as BuyAmount,

       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty else 0 end) as SellQty,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellRate,
       sum (case when Buy_sell=2 then Trade_Qty*Market_Rate else 0 end) as SellAmount
from tradeFile
where Party_Code="+@pcode+" and Sauda_Date like "+ @saudaDate+"%"+" and Scrip_Code="+@scripCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use concatenation for literal characters, it'll work:

```
where Party_Code=@pcode and Sauda_Date like @saudaDate+'%' and Scrip_Code=@scripCode
```